# Any way I can evaluate this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

So, *Mathematica* can't evaluate it. Any workaround?

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^\beta + 1}$$

The code is:

```
Integrate[1/(Sin[θ/2]^β + 1), {θ, 0, π}]
```

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code for the `Integral[]`

Comment: Works for me in 9.0.1... what returns for you?

Comment: Just prints back the integral. I'm using 9.0 on Linux...

Comment: @rasher It doesn't work here either. V9.0.1.0 on Win

Comment: @belisarius: Oops, I added the assumption of theta in reals by habit, that returns a result...

Comment: I do not think there is closed form solution for this. Even the indefinite integral does not evaluate. Tried Maple also and Rubi. You need to use Numerical integration after giving specific value for beta. Even assuming `beta` is integer did not help.

Comment: btw, you can ask this in the math group. There could be some smart transformation/substitution that makes it possible to do this.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies!

Answer (score 11):

This is not an answer, but a hint how to possibly proceed. It is a pity to pass on some nice Wolfram Language abilities. Let me know if I should remove it.

Idea is: I think **YOU** should be the first to derive this integral - if it is possible. Consider only rational numbers. If this integral behaves smoothly - which it obviously does:

```
DiscretePlot[NIntegrate[1/(Sin[s/2]^b + 1), {s, 0, Pi}], {b, 0, 3, .1}]
```

[image]

we can consider integration only with rational exponents because they can fill between irrational and transcendental exponents pretty well to represent smooth behaviour. Then for some simple $\beta$ you'll get all sorts of formulas - no consistency:

```
Integrate[1/(Sin[s/2]^(1/2) + 1), {s, 0, Pi}]
```

$2 \sqrt{2} E\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-2$

```
Integrate[1/(Sin[s/3]^(1/3) + 1), {s, 0, Pi}]
```

$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(\left(88 (-1)^{3/8} \sqrt[6]{4-2 \sqrt{2}} \left(10 \left(58+41 \sqrt{2}\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3};\frac{7}{6};17-12 \sqrt{2}\right)-\left(24+17 \sqrt{2}\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{5}{12};\frac{17}{12};17-12 \sqrt{2}\right)\right)+(20+20 i) \sqrt[6]{2} \left(22 \left((17+7 i)+(12+5 i)
   \sqrt{2}\right)-7 \sqrt[6]{2} \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{2}-4} \left((7+3 i)+(5+2 i) \sqrt{2}\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{11}{12};\frac{23}{12};17-12 \sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)+55 \left((41+99
   i)+(29+70 i) \sqrt{2}\right) \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2+2 \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)\right)}{55 \left((41+99 i)+(29+70 i) \sqrt{2}\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}$

which is pretty terrifying. But I think these are all simplifications form the [Meijer G function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html) as can be seen from more general $\beta$:

```
Integrate[1/(Sin[s/2]^(5/7) + 1), {s, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[1/(Sin[s/2]^(7/5) + 1), {s, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Try it with other fractions. So if you can figure out how arguments of Meijer G function are filled in you can probably publish a paper ;-)

Comment: omg who knew something that looks so innocuous could be terrifying as hell. BTW I'm just curious why you chose DiscretePlot. I used Plot* and got a smooth curve that looks like yours.
* Plot[NIntegrate[1/(Sin[s/2]^(\[Beta]) + 1), {s, 0, Pi}], {\[Beta], 0, 
  3}]

Comment: @seismatica I wanted to remind people it exists ;-) - rarely used. Smoothness is an illusion - there is sampling anyway: `Plot[NIntegrate[1/(Sin[s/2]^b + 1), {s, 0, Pi}], {b, 0, 3}, 
 Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Red]` It is faster - because you control sampling.

Comment: probably follows from Eulers reflection formula : `Sin[x/2] == Pi / ( Gamma[x/(2 Pi) ] Gamma[1 - x/(2 Pi) ] )`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a series-expansion way of doing your integral.

Expand the integrand as

```
Sum[(-1)^n Sin[θ/2]^(n β), {n, 0, ∞}]

(* 1/(1+Sin[θ/2]^β) *)
```

Integrate each term in the sum using

```
Integrate[Sin[θ/2]^(n β), {θ, 0, π}]

(* ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[π] Gamma[1/2 (1 + n β)])/Gamma[1 + (n β)/2], Re[n β] > -1] *)
```

Fold it all together to obtain

```
Sum[(-1)^n (Sqrt[π] Gamma[1/2 (1 + n β)])/Gamma[1 + (n β)/2], {n, 0, ∞}]
```

This gives the same numerical result as direct evaluation using `NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a way which will give you a the final solution in terms of $\beta$. The idea is generate a `Table` of solution for different $\beta$ value and then find a fitting function. I choose here $-10<\beta<10$.

```
data = Table[{\[Beta],NIntegrate[1/(Sin[\[Theta]/2]^\[Beta] + 1), {\[Theta],0,\[Pi]}]}, {\[Beta], -10, 10, .5}];
ListPlot[data]
sol1 = Interpolation[data] ;(*Interpolation*)
Plot[sol1[x], {x, -10, 10}, Epilog -> Point[data],PlotLabel->"sol1"]
sol2[x_] = Fit[data, Table[x^n, {n, 0, 20}], x]; (*Polynomial fit*)
Plot[sol2[x],{x,-10,10},Epilog->Point[data],PlotLabel->"sol2"]
```

[image: sol1,sol2]

So both $\rm sol1[\beta]$ and $\rm sol2[\beta]$ are your solution which you can see from the plots. Regarding $\rm sol2[\beta]$ you better use higher order polynomial (I use here 20) to get better result.

Following the suggestion by @george2079, you can also guess an approximate function for your solution with some unknown parameter and get an approximate (close enough) solution by fitting it. Here I show it for `a+b ArcTan[c x]`.

```
guess[x_] := a + b ArcTan[c x]
A = FindFit[data, guess[x], {a, b, c}, x];
sol3 = guess[x] /. A
Plot[sol3, {x, -10, 10}, Epilog -> Point[data], PlotLabel -> "sol3"]
```

[image: sol3]

and your final solution is $\rm 1.5708 + 0.776552 Tan^{-1}(0.554812 x)$. As suggested by @george2079, I think the 1.5708 will converge to $\pi$ if you consider more points. Anyway you may not be lucky enough every time to get such a nice guess.

Comment: nice approach. - Notice the function asymptotes to `{0,Pi}` as 'b->+/- Infinity`, which suggests you might look for some better approximating functions. ( Something like `Pi/2 + ArcTan[ a b^n ]` )

Comment: I agree @george2079. But all the time you may not be lucky enough to have such a nice function. I edit my answer according to your suggestion.