# How to calculate this integral?

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to Integrate the following Integral :

$\int_1^{\infty } \dfrac{\left(x^2-1\right)^{13/2} e^{-ax} }{x^{10}} \, dx \,\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(a=\textrm{real>0})$

Mathematica didn't calculate this integral. Maybe it is too complicated to be done.

In Mathematica input form:

```
Integrate[Exp[-a x] (x^2 - 1)^(13/2)/x^10, {x,1,Infinity}]
```

If I simply enter that into Mathematica, it instantly returns the same expression. 
How do I go about this? Is there any tricks that can be applied?
Thank's.

Comment: I'm also unable to get MMA to calculate the integral symbolically.  However, you can calculate it numerically for a given value of a: NIntegrate[(Exp[-a x] (x^2 - 1)^(13/2)/x^10) /. {a -> 0.1}, {x, 
  1, \[Infinity]}]

Comment: check this one
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48766/any-way-i-can-solve-this-integral

you probably have to replace `Infinity` with a large number to use these schemes.

Comment: You should define contours appropriately, `-1` and `1` are the branch points, thus approaching `1` you should know how to tackle this integral. As a reference examine this answer [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090)

Comment: is there a way to get the analytical result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way to get an exact symbolic expression for the integral.

Use the notation `fi[m,n,a]` to denote `Integrate[(Exp[-a x](x^2 - 1)^(m/2))/x^n, {x, 1, Infinity}]`.

Define integration by parts, where the boundary term vanishes.

```
fi[m_, n_, a_] /; m > 0 && n > 1 :=
  (m fi[-2 + m, -2 + n, a] - a fi[m, -1 + n, a])/(-1 + n);
```

See how we're doing so far.

```
fi[13, 10, a] // Expand

(*
  143/3 fi[3, 0, a] + 9295/384 a^2 fi[5, 0, a] - 
  3003/128 a fi[5, 1, a] + (3289 a^4 fi[7, 0, a])/2688 - 
  143/32 a^3 fi[7, 1, a] + (143 a^6 fi[9, 0, a])/10368 - 
  143/960 a^5 fi[9, 1, a] + (13 a^8 fi[11, 0, a])/362880 - (
  13 a^7 fi[11, 1, a])/10080 - (a^9 fi[13, 1, a])/362880
*)
```

Define how the `fi[m_, 0, a_]` cases evaluate.

```
fi[m_, 0, a_] /; m > 0 =   
  Assuming[Re[m] > 0 && Re[a] > 0, Integrate[Exp[-a x] (x^2 - 1)^(m/2), {x, 1, ∞}]]

(* (2^((1 + m)/2) a^(1/2 (-1 - m)) BesselK[(1 + m)/2, a] Gamma[1 + m/2])/Sqrt[π] *)
```

See how we are doing so far.

```
fi[13, 10, a] // Expand

(*
  (143 BesselK[2, a])/a^2 + (46475 BesselK[3, a])/(128 a) + 
  16445/128 BesselK[4, a] + 5005/384 a BesselK[5, a] + 
  143/384 a^2 BesselK[6, a] - 3003/128 a fi[5, 1, a] - 
  143/32 a^3 fi[7, 1, a] - 143/960 a^5 fi[9, 1, a] - (
  13 a^7 fi[11, 1, a])/10080 - (a^9 fi[13, 1, a])/362880
*)
```

Define how the `fi[m_, 1, a_]` cases evaluate, using differentiation w.r.t. `a` under the integral to get rid of the `1/x` factor, then integrating w.r.t. `a` afterwards.

```
fi[m_, 1, a_] /; m > 0 =   
  Assuming[Re[m] > 0 && Re[a] > 0,    
  Integrate[-Exp[-a x] (x^2 - 1)^(m/2), {x, 1, ∞}] //       
  Integrate[#, a] & //      
  Simplify //
  (# - (Limit[#, a -> ∞]//FullSimplify)&)]

(*
  -(1/2) π Csc[(m π)/2] + 
  1/4 a^-m Sqrt[π]
  Gamma[1 + m/2] (a^(1 + m) Sqrt[π]
  HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2}, {(3 + m)/2, 3/2}, a^2/4]
  - 2^(1 + m) Gamma[-(m/2)] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{-(m/2)}, {1/2 - m/2, 1 - m/2}, a^2/4]) Sec[(m π)/2]
*)
```

The last step fixes the constant of integration to ensure that the result goes to 0 (as it should) as `a` goes to infinity.

However, if `m` is an odd integer then the `Sec[(m π)/2]` factor blows up, and the factor containing the difference between the two `HypergeometricPFQRegularized` terms goes to zero, but these factors have a well-behaved product. So we need to manually intervene to make the expression manifestly finite when `m` is an odd integer.

It is sufficient to do a series expansion about odd integer values of `m` to extract the relevant coefficients. Here is how I did it.

```
factor1 = Assuming[m0 ∈ Integers && m0 >= 0, 
  SeriesCoefficient[
  a^(1 + m) Sqrt[π]
  HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2}, {(3 + m)/2, 3/2}, a^2/4] - 
  2^(1 + m) Gamma[-(m/2)] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{-(m/2)}, {1/2 - m/2, 
    1 - m/2}, a^2/4], {m, 2 m0 + 1, 1}] // FullSimplify];

factor2 = Assuming[m0 ∈ Integers && m0 >= 0, 
  SeriesCoefficient[Sec[(m π)/2], {m, 2 m0 + 1, -1}]];
```

Gather the pieces together, and rewrite the definition for the `fi[m_, 1, a_]` cases.

```
fi[m_, 1, a_] /; m > 0 =
  -(1/2) π Csc[(m π)/2] + 1/4 a^-m Sqrt[π] Gamma[1 + m/2] (factor1 factor2 /. m0 -> (m - 1)/2)

(*
  (-(1/2))*Pi*Csc[(m*Pi)/2] - (Gamma[1 + m/2]*Sec[(1/2)*(-1 + m)*Pi]*
    (a^(1 + m)*(2*
      HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {3/2, 3/2 + m/2}, 
       a^2/4]*(-Log[4] + 2*Log[a] + 
                 PolyGamma[0, -(1/2) + (1 - m)/2]) + 
     Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[2 + (1/2)*(-1 + m)]*                  
      Derivative[{0}, {1, 0}, 0][
        HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1/2}, {2 + (1/2)*(-1 + m), 
        3/2}, a^2/4]) +        
  4^(1 + (1/2)*(-1 + m))*Gamma[-(1/2) + (1 - m)/2]*
   Gamma[2 + (1/2)*(-1 + m)]*
         (Derivative[{0}, {0, 1}, 0][
       HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{-(1/2) + (1 - m)/
         2}, {(1 - m)/2, 1/2 + (1 - m)/2}, 
              a^2/4] + 
     Derivative[{0}, {1, 0}, 0][
       HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{-(1/2) + (1 - m)/2}, 
              {(1 - m)/2, 1/2 + (1 - m)/2}, a^2/4] + 
     Derivative[{1}, {0, 0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][
              {-(1/2) + (1 - m)/2}, {(1 - m)/2, 1/2 + (1 - m)/2}, 
      a^2/4])))/(a^m*(4*Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[2 + (1/2)*(-1 + m)]))
*)
```

Numerically verify that this gives you the right answer.

```
With[{m = 13, n = 10, a = RandomReal[{10^-6, 3}]},
 {NIntegrate[(Exp[-a x] (x^2 - 1)^(m/2))/x^n, {x, 1, ∞}], fi[m, n, a]}]
```

The required integral is then

```
fi[13, 10, a] // Expand

(* Lots of HypergeometricPFQ and HypergeometricPFQRegularized *)
```

The symbolic result looks incredibly messy to me, so maybe there are some further simplifications that could compress it down somewhat ...

Comment: Cool. +1.  Your polynomial part agrees with my polynomial part.  I guess the rest of it simplifies to the `MeijerG` part of my answer.

Comment: Indeed, my messy `BesselK` + `HypergeometricPFQ` + `HypergeometricPFQRegularized` expression is numerically the same as your nice `MeijerG` term. So, combining my power series piece with your `MeijerG` piece solves the problem nicely. I also noticed that you can directly obtain my symbolic power series from your numerical power series by evaluating `Pi Rationalize[Expand[<your power series>/N[Pi]],10^-10]`, but that needs a bit of hindsight to pull off with confidence!

Comment: @ Stephen Luttrell, I am very grateful for your help.
Thank you again for everything you’ve done.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to get an approximate symbolic expression for the integral.  Some of the coefficients are approximate because at some points in the process we need the value of a definite integral at `a = 1`, and unfortunately those integrals have to be computed numerically.

First, a lemma:  Let $f(a) = \int_1^\infty g(x, a) \; dx$.  Then $f(a) = f(1) + \int_1^a \int_1^\infty {\partial g \over \partial a}(x, a) \; dx \; da$ under suitable conditions for $g$.

The gist is that we can differentiate with respect to `a` first, then integrate with respect to `x`, and finally integrate with respect to `a`.  This can be helpful since ${\partial g / \partial a}$ has a different form than $g$; it might turn into something that can be integrated.  In the OP's case, if we have to differentiate *ten times* (which gets eliminates `x` from the denominator), we get to an integrate *Mathematica* will solve.

```
i1 = Simplify[
  Integrate[D[Exp[-a x] (x^2 - 1)^(13/2)/x^10, {a, 10}], {x, 1, Infinity}],
  a > 0]
(* 135135 BesselK[7, a] / a^7 *)
```

Next we'll calculate the constants (the $f(1)$ values) for each antiderivative.  These are the integrals that do not evaluate symbolically.

```
ClearAll[ni];
ni[n_Integer, a0_?NumericQ, opts___] :=
 NIntegrate[D[Exp[-a x] (x^2 - 1)^(13/2)/x^10, {a, n}] /. a -> a0, {x, 1, Infinity}, opts]

nii = Table[ni[k, 1, WorkingPrecision -> 50], {k, 0, 9}];
```

Next we'll integrate ten times.  There are numerical issues, so we converted the numbers above to infinite precision representations.

```
i2 = Block[{k = 0, n = SetPrecision[Reverse@nii, Infinity]}, 
  Nest[
   With[{int = Integrate[#, a]}, n[[++k]] + int - (int /. a -> 1)] &,
   i1, 10]];
```

This is gives the answer but there are many exact `MeijerG` expressions from the repeated integrations.  For practical use, it would be faster to convert them once to approximate numbers.  Here is a way to get 50-digit reals:

```
integral50 = Block[{nh, $MaxExtraPrecision = 100},
  SetAttributes[nh, NHoldAll];
  N[i2 /. g_MeijerG /; Not[FreeQ[g, a]] :> nh[g], 50] /. nh -> Identity
  ]
```

The even-power coefficients are in the range $10^{-48}$ to $10^{-45}$, which suggests they might be zero.  If we recompute `nii` and then the integral with 200 digits of precision, the coefficients drop to the range $10^{-198}$ to $10^{-196}$ which strongly suggests that they are zero.

```
nii = Table[ni[k, 1, WorkingPrecision -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 20], {k, 0, 9}];
i2 = Block[{k = 0, n = SetPrecision[Reverse@nii, Infinity]}, 
   Nest[With[{int = Integrate[#, a]}, n[[++k]] + int - (int /. a -> 1)] &, i1, 10]
   ];
integral200 = Block[{nh, $MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
   SetAttributes[nh, NHoldAll];
   N[i2 /. g_MeijerG /; Not[FreeQ[g, a]] :> nh[g], 200] /. nh -> Identity
   ];

integral = Rationalize[integral200] // Chop
(*
  36.85235444816464... a   -  7.01949608536469... a^3 + 
   0.23398320284548... a^5 -  0.00202582859606... a^7 +
   4.32869358133514...*10^-6 a^9 -
     135135/256 MeijerG[{{11/2}, {}}, {{-2, 0}, {1/2}}, a/2, 1/2]
*)
```

(Note: I replaced the coefficient of `MeijerG` by means of `Rationalize`, since it is in fact exact.  The coefficients of the polynomial part are approximate.  The relatively small coefficient of `a^9` did not change with the change in precision.)

Plot:

```
Plot[integral, {a, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am very grateful for your help. Thank you again for everything you’ve done.

Comment: @betatron  You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

You can have an analytical result, though not exact. I have several times addressed the analogous questions. You may look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19047/how-can-i-solve-an-equation-with-symbolic-coefficients/19051#19051) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15568/how-can-i-solve-tant-t-fx-for-t-as-a-function-of-x/15599#15599) where the approach is described within another problem depending upon a single parameter. 
I will consider your particular case fixing the domain of variation of the parameter `a` between 0.5 and 2. It is just for shortness. One may choose whatever he wants.  Let us make a table like the following:

```
J = Table[{a, NIntegrate[Exp[-a x] (x^2 - 1)^(13/2)/x^10, {x, 1, Infinity}]}, {a, 0.5, 2,0.1}];
```

Now we have a list of points with the structure {a, J(a)} and we can fit it with any reasonable function within this interval:

```
    ff = FindFit[int, k1*Exp[-k2*a] + k3, {k1, k2, k3}, a]
Show[{
  ListPlot[int, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["a", Italic, 16], Style["J", Italic, 16]}],
  Plot[k1*Exp[-k2*a] + k3 /. ff, {a, 0.5, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> All]
  }]
```

This yields the parameters of the fitting function:

```
(*   {k1 -> 3504.27, k2 -> 7.62848, k3 -> 0.650277}  *)
```

and the plot to check the fitting quality visually. It should look like the following:

[image]
where the blue points show the values of the integral, and the red line shows the fit.

If you need to get a better quality you may think about the modification of the function. For example, like this:

```
    Manipulate[
 ff = FindFit[int, (k1*Exp[-k2*a] + k3)/a^\[Alpha], {k1, k2, k3}, a];
 im2 = Show[{
    ListPlot[int, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.01]}, 
     PlotRange -> All, 
     AxesLabel -> {Style["a", Italic, 16], Style["J", Italic, 16]}],
    Plot[(k1*Exp[-k2*a] + k3)/a^\[Alpha] /. ff, {a, 0.5, 2}, 
     PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]
    }], {\[Alpha], 0.1, 3}]
```

You should see the following:

[image]

on the screen. The fit is somewhat better. Of course, the larger is the fitting interval, the more challenging is the task of guessing a good fitting function.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, you can calculate the integral for a specific value of `a`.  Here's a plot of the integral as a function of `a`:

```
 Plot[NIntegrate[(Exp[-a x] (x^2 - 1)^(13/2)/x^10), {x, 1, Infinity}], {a, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "Integral"}]
```

[image]